# Restore the previous input value by clicking reset button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reset, restore

I am working on a form which I have added a reset button which it should allows the user to go to the previous change which he made. This principle is similar like ctrl+z command. I could use that, but as far as I see for Safari opens the previous tab, which is not helpful.

I think a possible way is to save the old value and compare with the new value. But I want to reset value for the previous one not with default value.

Here my piece of code:

```js
 function restoreValue(){
                var oldValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                var newValue = element.value;
          
                if(oldValue == newValue)
      
                {
                    newValue = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
                    oldValue = newValue;
                    
                }

                ...........................................
            }
```

```css
   input{
                width: 200px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                border: 1px solid gray;
            }
            .mandatory{
                font-weight: bold;
                color: black;
            }
            .optional{
                font-weight: normal;
                color: black;
                font-style: italic;
            }
            .warning{
                border: 1px solid yellow;
                width: 200px;
            }
```

```html
     <form>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="mandatory" id="lastname" name="lastname">
                                Lastname
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="lastname" name="lastname"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="mandatory" id="firstname" name="firstname">
                                Firstname
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="firstname" name="firstname"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label class="optional" id="aliasFirstname" name="aliasFirstname">
                                Alias Firstname
                            </label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input id="aliasFirstname" name="aliasFirstname"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" onclick="">Reset</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Did you try history.back() method? (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns an HTMLCollection, not a single value, so surely you can't compare it to a previous value - you have to iterate through the collection using `.forEach` or `.filter` and extract the `.value`. Also, what is `element` you are reading from on line 3?

Comment: Have you considered employing something like `localStorage`? It's well-supported in major browsers, simple to access, simple to clean, and just might fit the case: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Hi @markp! I've searched for your example and seems to be interesting! Thank you for answear!

Comment: Hi @Dexter0015! I think your method will get the previous browser's closed tab. Is that possible to do only for input textbox?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` won't give you the value, but rather an array of elements that you can loop through. But I guess that you meant to select the field and read the `value` attribute. That won't work because its value is always *the current* value of the field.

You could use the `reset()` method of the form to reset all the values to the *initial* values.

But if you want to revert changes one by one like an undo, you will have to listen to changes (`input` event would cover typing, cutting and pasting), store each change somewhere, and listen to ctrl+z (on `keydown`) to assign the last value you stored when it happens. The browser already does this for you though... Please explain what's the point of this to understand you better.

Comment: Hi Gabriel.
The reason why I want to add is that costumer forgets to someting and he knows that made a change few seconds ago and he wants to see it again.

Regarding the keydown, is that a possible as ctrl+z not to restore the last closed tab (Safari)?

Comment: Yes, it is. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a basic state management strategy with a debounce function to restore captured values; https://youtu.be/4Ig9zf7sX94

[image]

https://gist.github.com/brianswisher/380d754794f0e7a71f068f82bc2cbc43

Comment: Hi Brian. I think I understand what you mean, but I want to go back to last value of the input field, not restore to the initial one.

Comment: That’s what the strategy I mention does. It goes back to the previous value. The tricky bit is knowing what is the previous value. That’s where a debounce function comes in handy. You use it to say, every so often, as the user types, that’s the new value. Clicking the button takes you back one at a time. At the end of the video, you’ll see me enter “a”, “b”, “c”, then “d”. When I hit the button it goes back to “c”, then “b”, then “a”. It’s a bit of state management with a debounce.

Comment: Now I get it. Thank you. This example helps a lot.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question#answer-285557)

Comment: I wanted to do a video with explanation because the topics of state management and debounce can be tricky. Also, I wanted to use a simple tool (Chrome JS console) to show it doesn’t need to be complicated. There is a link to a public gist in the video’s description; to get at code to copy and paste. I edited my answer to add the link at the bottom of the post.